# How to compile this both in clang and gcc?

Tags: c++

The below code compiles in g++ but error out in clang++. How to fix this code so that it can compile in both?

```
class A {
    private:
        template<int _N> class B {
            public:
                static constexpr int N = _N;
        };
        class C {
            public:
                template <typename B>
                B* func();
        };
};

template <typename B>
B* A::C::func()
{
    constexpr int N = B::N;
}
```

Comment: It compiles in clang++11.

Comment: This code should not compile in any compiler, at least if you try to use it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you describe why the code should not compile? I think there should be a `return` statement inside `func`'s definition. But not having a return statement should compile fine with a warning of missing return statement. Is there any other reason you said the code should not compile?

Comment: `template<int _N>` Don't do that. `_N` name is reserved to the language implementation. By using it as a template parameter, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

Comment: *"error out in clang++"*. Might be fine to show the error then.

Comment: @Joey The `B* A::C::func()` does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

clang prior clang 11 is unbale to resolve the name `B` properly. The solution is use another template parameter name:

```
template <typename D>
D* A::C::func()
{
    constexpr int N = D::N;
}
```

The full example requires the public access to A::C at least or a friend function.

```
class A {
    private:
        template<int N_> class B {
            public:
                static constexpr int N = N_;
        };
        class C {
            public:
                template <typename B>
                B* func();
        };
    friend int main();
};

template <typename D>
D* A::C::func() {
    constexpr int N = D::N;
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    A::C c;
    auto *n = c.func<A::B<0>>();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a compiler bug for clang then? I mean using name `B` should also work right?

Comment: `B::N` is working in clang 11.0.0++. I assume it was a bug in the older clang. `typename B`  in `B::N` should be the first attempt in name resolution.

Comment: Ok so the comment by NathanOliver in OP's original question is incorrect right? Because there is nothing wrong with the code itself and it is a compiler issue. Except that the OP forgot to add a `return` statement inside `func`'s definition.

Comment: His comment is correct for a practical usage.

Comment: I mean according to the standard C++ there is nothing wrong(except the missing return statement ofcourse). Also, he did not clarify whether he is talking about the missing return statement or something else.

Comment: The code in the question is correct syntactically.

Comment: Thank you all. I am using older clang. clang-11 actually works. I did workaround with older version by changing the code as you described.